# How do I have two post routes for the same class in RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit

Since I couldn't figure out how to set up two different POST resource paths for the same class , I tried manually creating the RKObjectLoader request but it seems to keep sending a GET request instead of a POST even though I've set the method to POST.  Here is my code

```
User *user = [[User alloc] init];
user.uname = uname;
user.pwd = pwd;


RKObjectManager *svc = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
RKObjectMapping* mapping = [svc.mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[User class]];

// what I was using before I needed two post resource paths//[svc postObject:user mapResponseWith:mapping delegate:self];

RKObjectLoader *loader = [svc loadObjectsAtResourcePath:authResourcePath objectMapping:mapping delegate:self];
[loader setMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
loader.userData = [NSNumber numberWithInt:RequestLogin];
loader.params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       uname, @"uname",
                       pwd, @"pwd",
                       nil];



[loader setSourceObject:user];
[loader send];
[user release];
```

Comment: This looks like the right way to go. Can you turn on RestKit Logging and post the relevant logs?

Comment: `RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);` You can replace `RestKit/Network` with `RestKit`, `RestKit/ObjectMapping`, and `RestKit/CoreData`. You can also change the "level" of the output with RKLogLevelDebug, etc. Trace gives you the most information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In cases where you have more than one path to POST or PUT to, the easiest thing to do is use the block form of the postObject: invocation and specify the destination resourcePath yourself:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:foo delegate:bar block:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.resourcePath = @"/my/destinationPath";
}];
```

We may introduce a named route concept at some point that would let you disambiguate the routes using names, but for now its purely based on the HTTP verb.

Note that you do NOT and cannot register the secondary path on the router -- you are sidestepping it completely for the secondary path.

Answer (score 4):

In order to complete Blake Watters answer if the different route need different objectMapping you will need to do:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:query delegate:saveJobQueryHandler block:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {
    loader.objectMapping = NEW_MAPPING;
    loader.resourcePath = @"/other/url";
    loader.targetObject = nil;  // Important
}];
```

For more information about loader.targetObject = nil; read [sendObject:delegate:block:](http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKObjectManager.html#//api/name/sendObject%3adelegate%3ablock%3a)